# $state.go() will only pass one parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameters

i'm trying to pass two params but only one is showing in the url which is booking_id. These are the different approaches i have tried.

```
url: "/followup/?booking_id?client_id",
url: "/followup/:booking_id?client_id",
url: "/followup/:booking_id:client_id",
url: "/followup/:booking_id/:client_id",
```

This is my state.go

```
$state.go('index.follow', {booking_id: id, client_id: $scope.client.id});
```

then in the controller i am accessing both in the $state.params.

```
$scope.booking_id = $state.params.booking_id;
$scope.client_id= $state.params.client_id;
```

Comment: Show code where you do `$state.go('index.follow', {booking_id: id, client_id: $scope.client.id});`. And why you acces from `$state` instead of `$stateParams`?

Comment: i dont know but i have change it to $stateParams now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check how you have defined your route ? While registering the route, check if its accepting one parameter or more

**For example:**

Your route registration should look something like this:

```
 .state("index.follow", {
       url: "/<route_name>/:booking_id/:client_id",
```